# Capistrano: Permission denied (publickey) though ssh git@github.com works

Tags: ruby, git, github, ssh, capistrano

I'm trying to configure Capistrano to deploy my Node.js project to one of my servers.

I created an ssh key, imported it to github, my server and my machine (with `ssh-add`). `ssh-add -l` lists the key, executing `ssh git@github.com` succeeds 
 - it displays github's default message:

> Hi myusername! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

I'm running Ruby 2.6.1 x64, Git 2.20.1 x64 & Windows 10 x64 (with OpenSSH installed via additional system features).

My `config/deploy.rb` file contains the following:

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "myproject"
set :repo_url, "git@github.myusername/myproject.git"
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, keys: 'C:/Users/myusername/mydirectory/id_rsa.pub' }
set :branch, "master"
```

And `config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
server "MYSERVERADDRESS", user: "MYSERVERUSER", roles: %w{apiServer}
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true, keys: 'C:/Users/myusername/mydirectory/id_rsa.pub' }
```

Running `cap production deploy` outputs the following:

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
Enter passphrase for C:/Users/myusername/mydirectory/id_rsa.pub:
MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS's password:
    ✔ 01 MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS 5.075s
      Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-myproject-production-myusername.sh 100.0%
      02 chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-myproject-production-myusername.sh
    ✔ 02 MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS 0.188s
00:05 git:check
      01 git ls-remote git@github.com:myusername/myproject.git HEAD
      01 Permission denied (publickey).
      01 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
      01
      01 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      01 and the repository exists.
#<Thread:0x00000000061737b0@C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
        12: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
        11: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
        10: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:18:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
         9: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:97:in `with'
         8: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:19:in `block (4 levels) in eval_rakefile'
         7: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:38:in `check_repo_is_reachable'
         6: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/git.rb:77:in `git'
         5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:78:in `execute'
         4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
         3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
         2: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
         1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:169:in `execute_command'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:99:in `exit_status=': git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
        1: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS: git exit status: 128 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
```

Which looks like it fails at the moment of executing `git ls-remote git@github.com:myusername/myproject.git HEAD`. What's strange is that when I run `git ls-remote git@github.com:myusername/myproject.git HEAD` manually, it succeeds (no matter if I do this in cmd or in git bash, I tried them both).

I also tried executing `cap production deploy` in git bash, but it is even worse, as it fails at the moment Capistrano expects me to input the RSA key's passphrase, throwing `Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)` before I am able to type anything, which does not happen when running the same in cmd:

```
$ cap production deploy
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp
Enter passphrase for C:/Users/myusername/mydirectory/id_rsa.pub:#<Thread:0x0000000006049d58@C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS: Bad file descriptor (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `noecho': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/prompt.rb:45:in `ask'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:67:in `rescue in load_data_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:60:in `load_data_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:44:in `load_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:232:in `block in load_identities'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:225:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:225:in `load_identities'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:117:in `each_identity'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:85:in `block in authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:246:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:116:in `read': Could not parse PKey: no start line (OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError)
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:116:in `block in classify_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:61:in `load_data_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/key_factory.rb:44:in `load_private_key'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:232:in `block in load_identities'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:225:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:225:in `load_identities'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:117:in `each_identity'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/methods/publickey.rb:19:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:85:in `block in authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:71:in `authenticate'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/net-ssh-5.1.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:246:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:63:in `with'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:145:in `create_command_and_execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:78:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-3.11.0/lib/capistrano/scm/tasks/git.rake:8:in `block (3 levels) in eval_rakefile'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.18.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as MYSERVERUSER@MYSERVERADDRESS: Bad file descriptor


Caused by:
Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor


Caused by:
OpenSSL::PKey::PKeyError: Could not parse PKey: no start line
```

Am I missing something in my configuration or is this a problem with Capistrano? Is there any way I can solve this?

Note: I've substituted data like username, github project name or disk paths in the attached all logs & config files